# Is Phalcon UTF8 compliant?

Tags: php, utf-8, phalcon

I was wondering what is the internals of Phalcon using with regards to UTF8?

For instance if I use something like this

```
echo strlen('hello'); // output 5
```

However

```
echo strlen('汉字/漢字'); // will output something like 10
```

strlen is not UTF8 compatible so one has to use the mb_strlen to be safe.

Does Phalcon use (internally) mb_* related functions? If not how can we ensure that everything internally is handled in a UTF8 manner to ensure compatibility with all languages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, PHP is binary safe,that means you can work with multibyte strings (like utf8 or other charsets), latin1 or ascii in a transparent way.

Phalcon, only uses strlen when working with directory names (not sure if anyone is using directories with multi-byte characters).